Issue with Vega Altair Heatmap: Cell Appearing Outside the Heatmap
I'm using Altair to create a heatmap based on some feature data. However, I've encountered an issue where one of the cells in the heatmap appears outside of the chart's boundaries when setting maxbins=20.
Here's a screenshot of the problem:

And here's the code I'm using to generate the heatmap:
import altair as alt

alt.Chart(df_features).mark_rect().encode(
    alt.X('y:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20)),
    alt.Y('x:Q', bin=alt.Bin(maxbins=20)),
    alt.Color('count():Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='greenblue'))
)


When I change maxbins to 30, the cell appears correctly within the chart, but I need the chart to work different values of maxbins. I suspect it has something to do with how the bins are calculated, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here you can find my df_features
Has anyone encountered this issue before? How can I ensure the cells are properly displayed within the chart boundaries, regardless of the maxbins value?

Can you include data of df_features? Also possible to raise an issue on GitHub for this

@Mattijn , thanks for the suggestion. I added the link to my df_features in the questions: https://gist.github.com/priscylla/778346f3bebe43a09e50279a78c49e8a

Thanks for including data! I have created an issue for this at the Vega-Lite repository: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/9418
